# oh-my-zsh's prompt is slow: how to fix this

Tags: terminal, zsh, prompt, oh-my-zsh

I'm using macOS 10.15.2 with iTerm2, zsh 5.7.1 and oh-my-zsh (theme robbyrussell).

I noticed that the prompt print is slightly slow respect to the bash one. For example, if I press <kbd>enter</kbd>, cursor initially goes at the beginning of the next line then, after a little while, the shell prompt comes in and the cursor is moved to its natural position. For example, if `→ ~` is the prompt when I'm in my home folder, and `[]` is my cursor, when I press enter I see:

**0 - Idle status**

`→ ~ []`

**1 - Immediately after pressing <kbd>enter</kbd>**

`[]`

**2 - Back to idle status**

`→ ~ []`

This slowness is particularly evident when I quickly press enter multiple times. In this case, I see some blank lines. This is what I see

```
→ ~
→ ~
→ ~

→ ~

→ ~


→ ~
→ ~
→ ~

→ ~ []
```

I come from bash shell and when I use bash, there is not such a slowness. I'm not sure this is an issue of oh-my-zsh or its natural behavior. I'd like to know more about this and, eventually, how to fix it. Thanks.

**PS**: the problem comes from oh-my-zsh and it persists even if I disable all the plugins.

**PPS**: I previously posted this question on SO. Thanks to [user1934428](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1934428/user1934428) for his help and for suggesting me to move this question here.

Comment: See this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12765344/oh-my-zsh-slow-but-only-for-certain-git-repo

Comment: I had this same issue. It wasn't related to being in a git repository. Interestingly, upon a fresh install of `zsh` -- i.e., after removing the config folder ~/.oh-my-zsh and reinstalling with the script on GitHub -- I noticed that the lag time was lower. It quickly increased to around 0.5 seconds per command with some time.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I don't know what oh-my-zsh puts in the prompt by default. Maybe it tries to identify the version control status, that's a very popular prompt component which might be time-consuming.

To see what's going on, turn on command traces with [`set -x`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html#index-XTRACE).

```
→ ~ 
→ ~ set -x
trace of the commands that are executed to calculate the prompt
→ ~ 
trace of the commands that are executed to calculate the prompt
→ ~ set +x
+zsh:3> set +x
→ ~ 
→ ~
```

If the trace is so long that it scrolls off the screen, redirect it to a file with

```
exec 2>zsh.err
```

This directs all error messages to the file, not just the trace. To get traces and errors back on the terminal, run

```
exec 2>/dev/tty
```

You can customize the trace format through [`PS4`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Parameters.html#index-PS4). This is a format string which can contain [prompt escapes](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Prompt-Expansion.html#Simple-Prompt-Escapes). For example, to add precise timing information:

```
PS4='%D{%s.%9.}+%N:%i> '
```

Comment: Great tips, it was `git_prompt_info` causing my issue. Thanks

Answer (score 20):

Checking if git dir is dirty seems to be causing the delay.

To speed up shell response, disable checking if dir is dirty by running in your terminal :

```
git config --add oh-my-zsh.hide-dirty 1
```

Remember to restart all your shells.

Answer (score 17):

I had the same issue with it, and it was also the `git_prompt_info` which causes the shell to slow down.
Be aware, that some oh-my-zsh themes use the git plugin sort of "hard coded" in their propmpts.

So consider one from the list you can get with this command

```
grep --files-without-match "git" ~/.oh-my-zsh/themes/*
```

Comment: Nice tip with `grep` thing. Saved me a ton of effort :P

Comment: if this is git_prompt_info issue this command will fix the issue: `git config oh-my-zsh.hide-info 1 --global`

Comment: Thanks a ton! Picking up a theme from list fixed the slowness. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 8):

I fixed the issue by modifying `~/.zshrc` and uncommenting this env variable:

```
# Uncomment the following line if you want to disable marking untracked files
# under VCS as dirty. This makes repository status check for large repositories
# much, much faster.
DISABLE_UNTRACKED_FILES_DIRTY="true"
```

I hope it helps!

Answer (score 4):

I fixed this in my laptop going to the ~/.oh-my-zsh folder, then ran `git pull`. There was around ~1200 commits pending. Then I close the iTerm and open it again. You'll get a prompt of oh-my-zsh being updated.

Answer (score 1):

Mac users: `+prompt_git` is what's taking so long but a new Xcode license is the real culprit.

If you use `git` that is bundled with Xcode, it's likely that there's an updated license that you needed to accept.

Run `sudo xcodebuild -license` and accept the new license, your ZSH prompt should return to normal speed.

Comment: This answer helped me find a fix: installing git with `brew install git` and then making sure that `/opt/homebrew/bin` appears on my PATH before `/usr/bin` meant that `/opt/homebrew/bin/git` became the new default (check with `which git`). Now the prompt loads at least 2-3x faster!

Answer (score 0):

vscode dev container terminal prompt was being slow for me, taking several seconds to return to prompt after completing any command. `set -x` showed the issue was with a `git ls-files` command being used to update the branch/dirty text in the prompt for a large repo.   Oddly `git ls-files` itself wasn't slow.

Setting `git config codespaces-theme.hide-status 1` solved it.